# Ways to signal that API returns an unmodifiable/immutable collection

Tags: java, immutability

Other than documenting it (obviously it should also be documented), using a special return type (I'm wary of limiting myself to an ImmutableX) or having the user find out at runtime, is there any other way of telling the users of an API that the collection they receive from said API is unmodifiable/immutable?

Are there any naming conventions or marker annotations that universally signal the same thing?

Edit: Unmodifiable and immutable do not mean the same thing, but for the purposes of this question, they are similar enough. The question basically boils down to letting the user know that the returned object does not fully honour its contract (ie. some common operations will throw a runtime exception).

Comment: "Unmodifiable" and "immutable" could mean different things in Java; `Collections.unmodifiableList` for example returns a List object that is unmodifiable, but not immutable - you can't call `add` or `remove` or `set` on it, but its contents can change through other means.

Comment: @immibis, I am aware, but thank's for pointing it out. I've amended the question with a brief explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a general naming convention but you might be interested in using this `@Immutable` annotation: http://aspects.jcabi.com/annotation-immutable.html 
Besides the documentation purpose this mechanism will also validate if your object is really immutable (during it's instantiation) and throw a runtime exception if it is not.

Comment: btw, `Immutable` present in much-adopted google findbugs maven artifact.

Answer (score 2):

Good and verbose solution would be to make your own UnmodifiableCollection wrapper class, and return it:

```
public UnmodifiableCollection giveMeSomeUnmodifableCollection() {
    return new UnmodifiableCollection(new LinkedList());
}
```

The name of the return type would be enough to make verbose statement about the unmodifiablility of the collection.

Answer (score 1):

1. Document it indeed
2. Provide API for checking if the given object is imutable collection
3. Return collection in wrapper that will hold information is the collection inside of it is mutable or not - my favorite solution
4. If possible, dont use mullable and immutable collections, but pick one of them. Results can always be immutable as they are results - why changing it. If there would be such need, it is a matter of single line to copy collection to new, mutable one and modify it (eg for chain processing)

Comment: For your third point, I assume the benefit of some wrapper with getX and isMutable methods over returning an ImmutableX is that the getX can return a native Collection interface. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Definetly, so there is no need to reinvent the wheel and provide special purpose collections. Another benefit is flexibility. If in the future you would ask on SO how to notify API users about other metadata of your collections, you will know what to do :) There is difference between immutable and unmodifiable - wrapper will clear can clear that out.

Comment: I'm on the fence about the third option. On the one hand, it does accomplish what is requested, on the other hand it adds a slightly convoluted layer of abstraction and forces the programmer to deal with what is essentially a bug in business logic (ie. if is mutable then add element, else .. what? a new, explicitly mutable/modifiable collection would be better in both cases).

Comment: This is my 4th solution - to unify results into same type of collections. Most straightforward, but is it possible in your case - it is up to you

Answer (score 1):

Writing an `@Immutable` annotation on the return type of a method is the best approach.  It has multiple benefits:

- the annotation documents the meaning for users
- a tool can verify that client code respects the annotation (that is, that client code does not have bugs)
- a tool can verify that the library code respects the annotation (that is, that library code does not have bugs)

What's more, the verification can occur at compile time, before you ever run your code.

If you want verification at compile time, you can use the [IGJ Immutability Checker](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#igj-checker).  It distinguishes between 
[`@Immutable`](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/api/org/checkerframework/checker/igj/qual/Immutable.html) references whose abstract value never changes, and 
[`@ReadOnly`](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/api/org/checkerframework/checker/igj/qual/ReadOnly.html) references upon which side effects cannot be performed.